# How to use Case insensitivity python lambda function

Tags: python

I have a DynamoDB table  with an attributes which have uppercase values.  I want to get the output for scan operation ; the input(" i='it' ") may be in any combination(lower+ upper, lower,upper). Please help me out for this. Thank you ...

"Lambda Code"

```
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table('Plant1')   
i="it"
response = table.query(
FilterExpression= Attr('PLANT_ID').contains(i) | 
Attr('CTRY_CD').contains(i))
items = response['Items']
return items
```

Comment: How about `Attr('PLANT_ID').lower().contains(i)` and similar?

Comment: @norok2 . it's not working getting -"'Attr' object has no attribute 'lower'"

Comment: what `type` is `Attr`?

Comment: @norok2.  "from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key, Attr"